# inserting new row in sqlite using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

Decide to use sqlite with hibernate.
First of all this is only test  project.

My entity classes

**Address.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 3, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 40, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Flat> flats;
```

**Flat**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FLAT")
public class Flat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID", length = 6, unique = true)
    private long id = 1L;
    @Column(name = "CRTN_DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_ID", nullable = false)
    private Address address;
    @Column(name = "ROOM_CNT", length = 1)
    private int roomCount;
    @Column(name = "AREA", length = 4)
    private long totalArea;
    @Column(name = "PHONE", length = 1)
    private String phone;
    @Column(name = "PRICE", length = 7)
    private float price;
```

so my problem:
When I try to insert new row like this

```
Flat flat = new Flat();
flat.setTotalArea(45);
flat.setCreationDate(new Date());
flat.setAddress(addressDAO.getByID(3));
flat.setRoomCount(2);
flat.setPrice(68000);
flat.setPhone("Y");
flat.setImages(new HashSet<ImageStorage>());
flatDAO.save(flat);
```

I get such output in my console:

```
Hibernate: insert into FLAT (ADDRESS_ID, CRTN_DATE, PHONE, PRICE, ROOM_CNT, AREA) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ERROR: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (NOT NULL constraint failed: FLAT.ID)
```

as I understand Hibernate didn't add null field (ID) into generated sql query. So maybe someone know how to fix this?
thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

[dialect I copied from here](https://github.com/gwenn/sqlite-dialect/blob/master/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/SQLiteDialect.java)

**dll**

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    NAME TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE FLAT
(
    ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    CRTN_DATE TEXT NOT NULL,
    ADDRESS_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ROOM_CNT INTEGER NOT NULL,
    AREA REAL NOT NULL,
    PHONE TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRICE REAL NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (ADDRESS_ID) REFERENCES ADDRESS (ID) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

Comment: could you add the ddl of your table? You also might want to post the hibernate dialect you are using ...

Comment: @Pieter, added all that you asked for. look at update

Answer (score 0):

If you define your ID column as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY you can omit the ID column in your insert statement (which hibernate does in your case).

Take a look at [Autoincrement In SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

Try this in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) (select sqlite database at the top)

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE flat(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
```

SQL

```
INSERT INTO flat(name) VALUES('flat 1');
INSERT INTO flat(id, name) VALUES(2, 'flat 2');
INSERT INTO flat(name) VALUES('flat 3');
select * from flat;
```

**UPDATE**

I've never used sqlite but according to the example above your code should work. You've defined your id column as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and hibernate doesn't include the id column in it's inserts.

Are you sure you haven't enabled "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"? The error makes sense (to me at least) if you are generating your tables with hibernate as your dialect isn't using the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY clause for your identity columns: take a look at `hasDataTypeInIdentityColumn()` and `getIdentityColumnString`.

Answer (score 0):

please add your custom dialect

```````
public class SQLiteDialect extends Dialect {

    public SQLiteDialect() {
        registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.TINYINT, "tinyint");
        registerColumnType(Types.SMALLINT, "smallint");
        registerColumnType(Types.INTEGER, "integer");
        registerColumnType(Types.BIGINT, "bigint");
        registerColumnType(Types.FLOAT, "float");
        registerColumnType(Types.REAL, "real");
        registerColumnType(Types.DOUBLE, "double");
        registerColumnType(Types.NUMERIC, "numeric");
        registerColumnType(Types.DECIMAL, "decimal");
        registerColumnType(Types.CHAR, "char");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "varchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARCHAR, "longvarchar");
        registerColumnType(Types.DATE, "date");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIME, "time");
        registerColumnType(Types.TIMESTAMP, "timestamp");
        registerColumnType(Types.BINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.VARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.LONGVARBINARY, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BLOB, "blob");
        registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "clob");
        registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "integer");
    }

    public IdentityColumnSupport getIdentityColumnSupport() {
        return new SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport();
    }

    public boolean hasAlterTable() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean dropConstraints() {
        return false;
    }

    public String getDropForeignKeyString() {
        return "";
    }

    public String getAddForeignKeyConstraintString(String constraintName, String[] foreignKey, String referencedTable, String[] primaryKey, boolean referencesPrimaryKey) {
        return "";
    }

    public String getAddPrimaryKeyConstraintString(String constraintName) {
        return "";
    }

    public String getForUpdateString() {
        return "";
    }

    public String getAddColumnString() {
        return "add column";
    }

    public boolean supportsOuterJoinForUpdate() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean supportsIfExistsBeforeTableName() {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean supportsCascadeDelete() {
        return false;
    }
    ``````
---------------------------------------------------
```````

public class SQLiteIdentityColumnSupport extends IdentityColumnSupportImpl {

```
@Override
public boolean supportsIdentityColumns() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public String getIdentitySelectString(String table, String column, int type)
        throws MappingException {
    return "select last_insert_rowid()";
}

@Override
public String getIdentityColumnString(int type) throws MappingException {
    return "integer";
}
```

```
add the property in properties

hibernate.dialect=com.common.config.db.SQLiteDialect // as per you class package

then  then configure your hibernate properties with   dialect 
    ("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
```